# ffmpeg working on wamp not in xammp

Tags: php, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I have created thumbnail image file of video file using **ffmpeg** in **php**. It is successfully working on ***wamp server***.Now want to use it in ***xampp server*** but its not working.... This is my code for creating thumbnails:

```
    $ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
    $videoFile = implode($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

    $imageFile = "thumb/".time()."_thumbs.jpg";
    $size = "800x420";
```

Why its not working on xampp... Thanks !!!!
        $getFromSecond = 25;
        $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";

Comment: Where does the IMG get created?

Comment: Try to `echo $cmd` and run the command from the command line. Does FFmpeg display an error?

Comment: @j_s_stack img created on "thumb" folder **line:3**

Comment: @user3409662 NO....Not any error

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" directive in your php.ini.